# Invalid Host header: Owned DNS domain pointing to AWS EC2 IP address running React App on port 3000

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2

I created an ec2 instance with public access to everything inbound and outbound. I containerized my local react app for front and backend (node js) (MERN) and pushed images to ECR and pulled and deployed into my EC2 instance. I am able to access everything with IP:Port no problems. I created a sub domain in my domain provider and an "A record" mapping to <IP>. Upon going to demo.example.com, it works, however trying to go to demo.example.com:3000 outputs "Invalid Host Header"

Would this be because demo.example.com could be https? and my IP is http?
any advice would be great

I know that ec2 uses apache webserver by default and I've tried to change my httpd conf files

`<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80> #this is an example     ServerName   demo.example.com:80 </VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are accessing your React app over HTTP.

The "Invalid Host Header" issue you're encountering when accessing demo.example.com:3000 is likely due to a mismatch between the configured host header and the actual host in the request.

In your Apache virtual host configuration, the ServerName directive should not include the port number. Modify it like this:

```html
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80> # replace 1.1.1.1 with your actual IP
    ServerName demo.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This should resolve the "Invalid Host Header" problem.

However, if you're accessing your React app over HTTPS (https://demo.example.com:3000), you need to consider a few additional points.

Comment: I've tried adding this to my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and doing "sudo systemctl restart httpd" it still provides the same error. what are the additional points? I am also currently unsure if demo.example.com is through http or https. It works when i use http and not https